# Drop TAble if exist and then create table

Tags: jdbc

i am creating java application using ms access database.

i have to create table "student" if not exit and if exist then drop table first then make table student.

i have writing code for it. for this i have made function boolean makeTable(Connection con,String tablename) and function boolean dropTable (Connection con,String tablename)

First time 
if exist table then maketable() return false but then call function dropTable() it return false also(table not deleted)

second time
 call  dropTable() then return true (table deleted successfully) but then call createTable() return false (table not created).

why this happens i don't know.

please help this.

if there is statement (Drop Table IF EXIST STUDENT)
or other way to doing this

thanks in advance.

--PARAG HUMANE

Answer (score 0):

Use [Connection.getMetaData().getTables()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) method. It return tables description.