# List all the tables in an Access database into a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, odbc

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

There is a set of created tables which are populated with data

The user will use the GUI to view the contents of the table or drop the table. Thats it, two operations only

The list of tables must be presented in a `JScrollPane` so that the use can select.

I have no clue how to do this.
I can do SQL though, the issue is with listing things into `JScrollPane`
Help will be appreciated...

Comment: table is a JTable or representation of DB table?

Comment: there are a few database browsers, but metadata are stored in JComboBox, have to change to JList

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov representation of database table.

Comment: May be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609627/drop-table-if-exist-and-then-create-table

Answer (score 1):

In order to get all of the tables from an Access data base, you have to query the TableDefs table.  This [article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-create-a-list-of-tables-or-queries-from-access/5047664) goes into more detail as to how you write the queries.

In order to display all of the tables from an Access database, you'll need to create a JList, which has a JScrollPane parent, which is contained in a main JPanel in a JFrame.  All of these components must live on the Swing Event Dispatch thread.

To understand more about Swing components, go through the [Oracle Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Comment: You should be more easily able to get a list from a schema against the Jet/ACE connection, rather than using an Access object.